# Ajax Request duplication

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, standards

My team seems to have a lot of different ways it makes AJAX calls, ranging from ok to horrible.
I was looking for some sort of template or wrapper that we could adopt but I hadn't found anything much out there.

Currently, most of us do something like this...

```
<script>
//typical ajax call from front end file
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
// code
}
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
httpRequest.open('POST', "ajax/file.php")
httpRequest.send('username=' + encodeURIComponent(username))
```

```
<?php
// Can this be abstracted out to one place?
$customer_id = $_SESSION['customer_id'];
$session_valid = SessionValidator::validateSession();

if(!$customer_id && $session_valid === false) {
    $return = [
        'error' => 'Your session has expired. Please <a class="link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login_modal">sign in again.</a>'
    ];
} else if(!$customer_id) {
    $return = [
        'error' => 'Could not find your customer ID. Please <a class="link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login_modal">sign in again.</a>'
    ];

} else {
    
switch ($_POST['action']){

    case "join":
        $return = Manager::customerJoin($customer_id);
        break;

    case "make_url":
        $customer = Manager::getByCustomersId($customer_id);
        $return = $customer->makeLink($_POST['url']);
        break;

    case "accept_payout":
        $return = Manager::payout($_POST["customers_customers_id"], $_POST["orders_product_ids"], $_POST["total"]);
        break;

    case "addLink":
        $customer = Manager::getByCustomersId($customer_id);
        $customer->link = $_POST["url"];
        $return = $customer->addAffliateLink($customer);
        break;
}

// OR 

$result = call_user_func($validPost['function'], $validPost);

// OR 

$result = call_user_method($validPost['function'], $validPost);

}
echo json_encode($return);
```

We have hundreds of files like this with varying degrees of efficacy and it got me annoyed but I haven't found a solution I like yet.

I've had thoughts about having a single abstract Ajax class and just adding more data about the calls I want to make from the frontend but I haven't figured out anything concrete yet.

Does anyone have a better method?

Comment: Is the javascript or PHP the issue that you are having? This is kind of more an opinion generating question if anything. Plus there might not be a real answer as the problems are unique to your system.

Comment: Definitely, the PHP files, Ill update the question to be more accurate.
The work we do on the backend is unique in each case, but how we do that work doesn't need to be unique in my opinion and I was hoping someone had a better idea of how to do that.